# Can't execute second MYSQLI query in same PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my code

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `accountsToDo` WHERE `OKrname` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $OKCUsername);

    /* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0){
    echo "Exists";
} else {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `accountsToDo`(`percentageOfMessages`, `RemoveDeletedAccounts`, `RemoveNoReply`, `RemoveNoResponse`, `minMatchPercent`, `minDistance`, `maxDistance`, `blacklistUsernames`, `userEmail`, `OKrname`, `OKword`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("iiiiiiissss", $percentageOfMessages, $RemoveDeletedAccounts, $RemoveNoReply, $RemoveNoResponse, $minMatchPercent, $minDistance, $maxDistance, $blacklistUsernames, $userEmail, $OKrname, $OKword);

    $stmt->execute();
}


/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

But now I'm getting the error,

> Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in line 147.

Line 147 is

`$stmt->bind_param("iiiiiiissss", $percentageOfMessages, $RemoveDeletedAccounts, $RemoveNoReply, $RemoveNoResponse, $minMatchPercent, $minDistance, $maxDistance, $blacklistUsernames, $userEmail, $OKrname, $OKword);`

Comment: Sounds like your prepare statement failed. Are you testing for errors? You may want to enable exceptions to avoid missing them.

Comment: `affected_rows()` isn't for SELECT. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php *"Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query."* - What you want is `num_rows()`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: No error checking whatsoever neither.

Comment: This check...insert pattern is very inefficient. If you have a natural unique key, just ru n the insert and poll the error message if you need to check the data exists.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is inserting into a todo table if the master table doesn't have a matching row, you don't need two statements.

```
INSERT INTO `accountsToDo` 
        (`percentageOfMessages`, `RemoveDeletedAccounts`, 
          `RemoveNoReply`, `RemoveNoResponse`, `minMatchPercent`, 
          `minDistance`, `maxDistance`, `blacklistUsernames`, 
          `userEmail`, `OKrname`, `OKword`) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `accountsToDo` WHERE `OKrname` = ?);
```

Bind your params and you have save a call to the db.  This has the advantage that "SELECT 1" acts as a cut operator so it is only evaluated until it finds the first TRUE.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Thanks for formatting it.  I was just "stringing it" for PHP.  Looks good :)

Comment: For some reason, it still doesn't feel like working. This is the code I have so far [http://hastebin.com/ofileleciz.php](http://hastebin.com/ofileleciz.php) And the error I'm getting is "Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between table name and a list of fields in your `$mysqli->prepare`

Try this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `accountsToDo` 
                        (`percentageOfMessages`,`RemoveDeletedAccounts`, 
                         `RemoveNoReply`, `RemoveNoResponse`, 
                         `minMatchPercent`, `minDistance`, 
                         `maxDistance`, `blacklistUsernames`, 
                         `userEmail`, `OKrname`, `OKword`) 
                         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

According to [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) $mysqli->prepare will return `FALSE` if statement caused an error

> UPDATE

Looks like your $mysqli->prepare is expecting 11 variables and you are trying to bind 12

Comment: That shouldn't matter. That only applies if it's a function.

Comment: For some reason, it still doesn't feel like working. This is the code I have so far http://hastebin.com/ofileleciz.php And the error I'm getting is "Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't have 
`$stmt->store_result();`
above the first `$stmt->execute();`